# $\lim_{x\to 0+}\ln(x)\cdot x = 0$ by boundedness of $\ln(x)\cdot x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I saw a proof that 
$$
 \lim_{x\to 0} \ln|x|\cdot x = 0
$$
where is is argued that for $x \in (0,1)$ we have
$$
 | \ln(x) x | = \left| \int_1^x x/t ~\mathrm d t \right|  = \left| \int_x^1 x/t ~\mathrm d t \right| \le \left|\int_x^1 1 dt\right| = |1 - x| \le 1
$$
and therefore the result follows, but why should the fact that $|\ln(x)x|$ is bounded imply it converges to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, what you have shown does not imply that the limit is zero. After all, the value of $\frac1x\cdot x$ is also bounded by $1$ but does not have a limit of $0$.

If your book says that the result follows soley from the bounds you wrote, it is wrong. I suggest, however, that you reread the entire argument made in the book.

Comment: indeed it says exactly this, but then it might be an error.

Comment: @Stefan Hmm, can you post a screenshot or a link, I am still doubtful...

Comment: it is from here, what cow_gone_mad wrote, but it is in german... http://matheplanet.com/default3.html?call=viewtopic.php?topic=135765&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F

Answer (score 0):

$x \ln(x)$ is monotonous as well (decreasing around 0), so it must have a limit.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{|x|}{2}$ is also decreasing around $0$, it is also bounded by $1$ for $x\in (0,1)$, yet the limit is not $0$. OP is asking why the limit is $0$, not whether the limit exists. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Agree, my point was that it implies there is a limit. Next step is to look on $x\rightarrow 0+$ for instance using a sequence (we know they all converge towards the same value) and explicitly show it tends towards 0, for instance the sequence $x_n = \exp(-n)$.

Comment: Sure, but the question is explicitly "does the boundedness imply that the limit is $0$"

Comment: It is an odd function, so proving that there is a limit proves that is has to be 0. I agree it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: It sure is. For example, it does not work if the function would be discontinuous at $0$, and it has not been proven that that is not the case...